# Getting errors when deploying device tree overlays

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am working on deploying device tree overlays on my Beaglebone Black.

The Linux version is:

```
Linux version 4.1.18-ti-r52 (root@b1-omap5-uevm-2gb) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) ) #1 SMP Thu Mar 10 00:41:28 UTC 2016
```

I am following the example at 
https://github.com/jadonk/validation-scripts/blob/master/test-capemgr/README.md.

I have also worked through the examples in Derek Molloys' Exploring BeagleBone Black book chapter 6.  In both of those cases I am running into the same error when I deploy the overlay.  The overlay appears to deploy properly, no errors are given when doing echo  > $SLOTS but when I look at the kernel messages using dmesg I get errors like what is shown below.  What is shown below is from following the jadonk example.

```
[ 1053.452639] bone_capemgr bone_capemgr: Using override eeprom data at slot 5
[ 1053.452664] bone_capemgr bone_capemgr: slot #5: 'Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,pinctrl-test-7'
[ 1053.455556] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin 44e10964.0 already requested by ocp:P9_42_pinmux; cannot claim for ocp:helper
[ 1053.467142] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin-89 (ocp:helper) status -22
[ 1053.474093] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: could not request pin 89 (44e10964.0) from group pinctrl_test_7_pins  on device pinctrl-single
[ 1053.486626] bone-pinmux-helper ocp:helper: Error applying setting, reverse things back
[ 1053.495157] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin 44e10964.0 already requested by ocp:P9_42_pinmux; cannot claim for ocp:helper
[ 1053.506627] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin-89 (ocp:helper) status -22
[ 1053.513582] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: could not request pin 89 (44e10964.0) from group pinctrl_test_7_pins  on device pinctrl-single
[ 1053.526118] bone-pinmux-helper ocp:helper: Error applying setting, reverse things back
[ 1053.534109] bone-pinmux-helper ocp:helper: Failed to select default state
```

Before deploy I see:

```
root@beaglebone:/lib/firmware# cat $SLOTS
 0: PF----  -1 
 1: PF----  -1 
 2: PF----  -1 
 3: PF----  -1 
 4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,cape-universaln
```

After deployment I see:

```
root@beaglebone:/lib/firmware# cat $SLOTS
 0: PF----  -1 
 1: PF----  -1 
 2: PF----  -1 
 3: PF----  -1 
 4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,cape-universaln
 5: P-O-L-   1 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,pinctrl-test-7
```

But dmesg shows the errors above.

Can you suggest what might be happening and/or how I might troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am past this problem. On another forum, cape-universaln and usage of config-pin was explained to me. cape-universaln is an overlay that provides a way to configure pins without writing overlays. There is good information on this at https://github.com/cdsteinkuehler/beaglebone-universal-io. The pin conflicts I was seeing were to be expected. I was trying to deploy an unneeded overlay on top of an already deployed overlay that provided a simpler way to configure pins. Still learning.

Comment: The universal IO was auto loaded in my Beagle Bone Linux debian 8 image. I had to edit `/boot/uEnv.txt` and set `cmdline=coherent_pool=1M quiet cape_universal=disable` (the `cape_universal` being the relevant parameter, obviously).